# SMTP Verification failed

Tags: civimail

SMTP settings are checked (with user@domain as login) and *Track replies using VERP in Reply-To header* is disabled (it worked before).
How come a generated email adress name is used as login, thus preventing CiviMAIL to send a test mail?
Drupal 7.61 CiviCRM 4.7.30

> Jan 09 07:00:10  [info] Ignoring exception thrown by nullHandler:
>   10005, Failed to add recipient: *user*@*domain*
>   [SMTP: Invalid response code received from SMTP server while sending email.
>   This is often caused by a misconfiguration in Outbound Email settings.
>   Please verify the settings at
>   Administer CiviCRM >> Global Settings >> Outbound Email (SMTP).
>   (code: 550, response: Verification failed for
>   < b.1223.8100.d34261f00e3242ab@*domain*>
>   This email address does not exist. Dit e-mail adres bestaat niet.
>   Sender verify failed)]

Comment: This looks like a change in your SMTP server.  I would show this error to whomever runs the mail server, they probably made a recent change that could cause this.

Answer (score 1):

My comment above notwithstanding, there is a possibility that this isn't a mail server issue.

If you recently upgraded to a newer version of PHP, you may have gone from a version that uses *mcrypt* to encrypt the outgoing mail password to one that doesn't.  To fix this, go to **Administer menu » System Settings » Outbound Mail** and re-enter your SMTP password and save.